# PHP: Usar SELECT DISTINCT y obtener últimos resultados de la tabla

Tags: php, mysql

Buenas a todos!

Soy principiante en el mundo del php y me surgió una duda que no he podido aclarar del todo mirando algunos post de aquí.

Estoy haciendo una query en una base de datos Mysql:

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT antenna_port, nombre, apellido, patente, auto, epc, first_seen_timestamp  
            FROM lectura
            WHERE first_seen_timestamp BETWEEN timestamp(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)) AND timestamp(NOW())
            GROUP BY epc"
```

Esta query me trae a la tabla los registros que hayan ingresado a la BD en el lapso de los últimos 15 minutos. Ingresan varios registros con el mismo ID, con lo cual debería saber a que hora fue el último ingreso, para esto necesito tomar el valor más reciente.

Tengo entendido que debo hacer como una sub-query pero aún no di en el clavo.

Cualquier ayuda va a ser muy agradecida!!

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Podría intentar tener un campo identity y traer el max() del query y así estaría siempre mostrando el último registro

Comment: cual id?? puedes aclararlo?

Answer (score 1):

Lo que debes agregar a tu consulta es un `order by` por el campo `first_seen_timestamp` descendentemente. Y además debes usar `top 1` de manera que el row que obtengas es el mas reciente.

Answer (score 0):

no se si te funcione de esta manera

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT antenna_port, nombre, apellido, patente, auto, epc, first_seen_timestamp, top 3 MAX(timestamp) AS MaxFecha   
            FROM lectura
            WHERE first_seen_timestamp BETWEEN timestamp(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)) AND timestamp(NOW())
            GROUP BY epc"
```

Comment: Daniel, decir "no se si te funcione" es que no estas seguro si esto ayuda a solucionar la pregunta, debes estar seguro, de otra forma esto solo sería un comentario, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que entiendo el id que viene repetido lo estas guardando en la columna `epc`. No hace falta hacer un subquery.

Te paso un ejemplo sencillo para que luego lo puedas implementar en tu query

```
create table #tabla (
    nombre nvarchar(100),
    apellido nvarchar(100),
    fecha datetime
)

insert into #tabla (nombre, apellido, fecha) values
('Clark', 'Kent', '2019-05-18'),
('Clark', 'Kent', '2019-06-22'),
('Bruno', 'Diaz', '2019-08-22')

select nombre, apellido, max(fecha) from #tabla 
group by nombre, apellido
```

En este ejemplo se usa la función `Max` para obtener la fecha mas nueva del agrupamiento.

En tu caso, tendrás que agrupar por todas las columnas que te sean necesarias de acuerdo al requerimiento que tengas y luego usar `max(first_seen_timestamp)` para obtener la fecha mas reciente